sed - combine two replace command into one line
I have below two line command to replace in files under current directory.
I would like to combine it to one line command to improve performance.
find . -type f -name '*' | xargs sed -i 's/hello_release_demo/hello_demo/g'
find . -type f -name '*' | xargs sed -i 's/hello_debug_demo/hello_demo/g'

How should I use one sed command to handle two similar replace?

xargs sed -i 'command1; command2; command3'

You can use an extended regular expression, with the -E option:
sed -E -i 's/hello_(release|debug)_demo/hello_demo/g'


You can use the -e parameter to pass multiple expressions to sed
find . -type f -name '*' | xargs sed -i -e 's/hello_release_demo/hello_demo/g' -e 's/hello_debug_demo/hello_demo/g'

Or, alternatively, using a regular expression works as well
find . -type f -name '*' | xargs sed -i 's/hello_\(release\|debug\)_demo/hello_demo/g'

Note that in the future, you can use man *command* to quickly get answers to such questions. in your case, man sed should have the information needed, which should be equivalent to the contents at https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed
